# Is it true that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \frac{(z_0+h)^n-z_0^n}{h} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \frac{(z_0+h)^n-z_0^n}{h}$ (Notice the index)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

There's a proof in my textbook where the author uses the followng equality,

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \frac{(z_0+h)^n-z_0^n}{h}-
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_n z_0^{n-1}
=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(\frac{(z_0+h)^n-z_0^n}{h} - nz_0^{n-1}\right)
$$

where $z_0,h$ are fixed values in some appropriate subset of $\mathbb{C}$. The details don't matter for my question, the point is that the two series are both convergent.

**The above equality doesn't seem justified to me**

The important thing here is not the specific summands, but the change of index in one of the series: in order for the above equality to hold we seem to need that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \frac{(z_0+h)^n-z_0^n}{h}
=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \frac{(z_0+h)^n-z_0^n}{h}
$$

before we can combine them, however this doesn't really seem to be true?

For example it isn't true that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^n$

**Am I missing something or is the author of the proof not justified in doing so?**

Comment: The expression $\frac{(z_0+h)^n-z_0^n}{h}$ equals to $0$ when $n=0$. So it doesn't add anything to the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is understood that $z^{n}=1$ when $n=0$. So $(z+h)^{n}-z^{n}=1-1=0$ so the term corresponding to $n=0$ vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

When $n=0$, the summand in the first series is simply $0$.